# Over Salesforce Marketing Cloud, How to create contact under the list?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-marketing-cloud, salesforce-mobile-sdk

Tried adding contact for Mobile Push channel in Marketing cloud through REST API(create_contact) and it is working but not able to add contacts within the specific contact list.

I created a contact list from the dashboard(MobilePush -> AddContact -> Lists -> CreateList -> FilteredList -> CreateFromFile -> Save as standard list).

After creating a list I found "EXTERNAL KEY" and "LIST ID" from the list properties.

Now I would like to create contacts within the list via create_contact REST API.